# Amadeus API does not show available direct flights

Tags: postman, amadeus, skyscanner

I am testing the Amadeus API with Postman (and with python as well). When I set for a certain date (2024-03-02) only direct flights from BUD (Budapest) to LHR (London Heathrow) it shows 0 results.
I checked on skyscanner and of course there are 3 direct British Airways flights for that day.

So, I would like to use amadeus api to get ONLY the direct flights as result. According to amadeus there are no direct flights (which is definitely not true as shown by skyscanner)!

Could someone please explain what is wrong with my code when I would like to get only the direct flights via the amadeus api?

[image: Postman screenshot]

[image: SkyScanner screenshot]

Comment: What does the Amadeus API documentation say about this?

Comment: Is your comment suppose to help in any ways @tomredfern? What are you trying to imply?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [API docs](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference), the following statement appears:

> Please also be aware that our test environment is based on a subset of
> the production, if you are not returning any results try with big
> cities/airports like LON (London) or NYC (New-York).

You are using the subdomain *test-api.amadeus.com* for Amadeus, but *skyscanner.net* for Skyscanner; so, the most likely explanation is that the live flights in Skyscanner production do not exist in the Amadeus test environment.

Based on this analysis, there is nothing "wrong with your code" as you suspect - you cannot rely on the same data being in two completely separate environments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it does not answer my question. I would like to get direct ONLY flights with amadeus api. According to the result of the api there are no such flights (which is not true, as skyscanner shows three direct flights for that day).

Comment: Tried with LON: 0 results. Only RyanAir has 5 direct flights for that day (not counting wizzair, easyjet and BA). So basically amadeus's test environment is rubish not worth one bit.... Shame.

Answer (score 0):

once you use the production environment you will get the same results as skyscanner. For accuracy in results one need to upgrade to the production environment and gradually to the enterprise version, as explained in amadeus for developers FAQ's and videos. For direct flights you might need to add other API's that are offered under full catalogue in enterprise version. I might not be right because i am also exploring amadeus self service API's, please add your insights about your project, that can be helpful for the community.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).